# Find best matching ranges below limit in defined set of numbers

Tags: iterative-method, search

I am trying to calculate the best set of cuts for some wood cutting to reduce the waste.

So: Given a set of numbers, the goal is to find the best matches below a limit (size of wood beam).

Example of the set of numbers:

```
const input = [
  4, 13.5, 17.5, 18.5, 20, 26, 43.5, 44.5, 
  45, 46, 54, 54.5, 55, 60, 61, 62, 70.5, 
  80.5, 103.5, 148.5, 78, 102, 10,
]
```

The limit in my case is `const limit = 300`.

Example of result I got so far:

```
SUM PARTS
300     148.5   80.5    61      10              
300     103.5   102     70.5    20      4           
300     78  62  60      55      45          
299.5   54.5    54      46      44.5    43.5    26  17.5    13.5
18.5    18.5
```

This result set is the output of an overly complex and long running set of functions that builds a set of all possible combinations and then searches the best combinations.

**Question** is how to solve this without excessively using CPU cycles?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SciComp!

Do you have any limits of how large your lists of sublength will get? Are you looking for the "optimal" solution, or for one that is "good enough"? The answer to this makes the difference if we are talking about heuristics or hard math, so to say.

I'd try to avoid testing all combinations by trying to make the discarding more efficient. When looping through your sorted array, you may return as soon as you have reached an element that will overstep your limit (remaining length of the planck), and all following elements will be bigger anyway. That way you should be able to avoid a large part of computational effort.

Have you checked the literature for existing algorithms? Maybe you can have a look at the well known [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and look for existing approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The set probably won't be very large (< 100 items) as it's really just about a private task I am aiming to solve. I haven't checked the literature as my math background is applied building construction math, which does not help in any way here. The hint about setting a min is good thought. One could even shift the min upwards in case it already got "used". Do you have a rough example of implementation for your answer?

Comment: Is that python you are using?--> https://pypi.org/project/binpacking/ and the implementation examples therein. Since you already have your length and limit in array form you should be able to use it more ore less out-of-the-box

Comment: Ist actually ES/JavaScript. Thanks for the link!